# Why doesn't a phone li-ion battery die for 5 years and a pc li-ion battery dies in 1-2 years?

Tags: power-management, battery, power

WHat is the major factor? heat?,size? consumption style like full discharge?

Comment: Laptop batteries are typically overcharged.  A few systems (like my Sony) can be set to not charge the battery to 100% but that's apparently the exception.  It helps to run the system on battery from time to time (though don't regularly run it flat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to replace the battery of my android phone every 18 months because it won't hold enough charge after being fully discharged on daily basis for 400+ days, so it's not really about what kind of device the battery is in.

The factor is mainly number of full discharge cycles and the operation condition. Lithium batteries can typically survive 400-600 full charge cycles and still hold a respectable amount of charge. However, if you constantly over-discharge it or use it under high temperatures its life will be drastically reduced. (Just 30 degrees Celsius is high enough !!)

Any temperature that is hot for humans is certainly too hot for li-ion batteries. That's places like the back or bottom of a laptop where the battery normally resides. If possible remove the battery when you're on a stable AC power and put it in the fridge. Never turn the phone back on if its automatically shutdown: you won't have enough time to do anything with it and you're killing the battery.

Read http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: Plus the quality of the battery itself. which can be night and day differences in: number of charges, length of time, suseptibility to conditions, even charge state and storage.  I have many cell items of various types in use and testing. The high quality ones have lasted more than 8 years, the low quality ones around 2, all of them treated very well.  Add to that again, the quality of the electronics on the battery itself, and charge curcuitry. Balance , and charge alogrythm.